# How to style input element so that inner text disappears when you click on the input element?

Tags: html, css

Sorry I know this question has probably been asked before, but do you know of any clean ways to style input elements so that the inner text disappears when you click on the input element?

Comment: use &('Yourelement').focus()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about using the `placeholder` attribute. As of HTML5, this is a default attribute of an input text element.

For older browsers that don't support this, you could use the JQuery Watermark plugin - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you have any idea why jquery won't add such a function into the mainline?  It's really awesome!

Comment: If you mean the JQuery core, it's not added because its a default HTML5 attribute. No need to include it into the core JS. The plugin is great because it helps older browsers, which don't support `placeholder`, to use the feature.

Answer (score 2):

What you appear to be looking for is the HTML5 [`placeholder`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute) attribute:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Placeholder text">
```

However, this is not supported in older browsers, so you will have to use a JavaScript shim to add the functionality. [Here's an example](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) of such a shim which does not depend on any external resources such as jQuery.

The shim linked to above allows you to simply use the `placeholder` attribute as shown above. Simply call `Placeholders.init()` on DOM ready and it will work. If the attribute is supported natively, it won't take effect.